# ReflectionException in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and I'm getting the following exception:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist' in /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:738

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you change the namespace using `php artisan app:name`?

Comment: try with `composer dump-autoload` from your terminal